# Pasar datos de un array de una funcion a otra funcion

Tags: java, poo, funciones

Muy buenas. Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase que me pida que haga varias funciones con un menú de las cuales la primera opción tiene que ser rellenar el array con números de entre -100 y 100 la cual está funcionando perfectamente. pero aquí viene mi pregunta en el caso 2 del menú tengo que hacer una media de todos los números de ese array. ¿Cómo puedo sacar los datos del array para meterlos a la función y poder hacer la media? Aquí dejo una foto de como está el código en este momento. Muchas gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Despues de casi dos años registrado, ¿no has visto que el código se pega como texto formateado y no en imágenes? ¿Para qué quieres "sacar" los datos de array? ¿No basta con declararlo antes del switch? ¿Porque ordenas el array cada vez que añades un número (dentro del for) en lugar de cuando ya tienes todos los números (tras el for)? Por último, por convención y legiblidad, los corchetes se ponen despues de la clase al declarar las variables que son arrays: int[] relleno.

Comment: declara el array de manera "global" fuera del switch , de esa manera podes usarlas en cada case que quieras.